# If http.path is set, is there a way to provide a route for /

Tags: java, routes, playframework

I have in my application.conf

```
http.path=/manage
```

So, when I go to http://localhost:9000/ I get a Not Found 404 page.

Is there a way to redirect `/` to `/manage/` while still keeping the app at `http.path=/manage` ?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/CQoBxQ0UBpI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, the `http.path` setting is used for,

> The URL path where the application runs on the server: use this if you do not host your Play application at the root of the domain you’re serving it from. This parameter has no effect when deployed as a WAR, because the path will be handled by the application server.

If this is not the case, then you may be better off using your routes file to manage the URLs, so that you specify both the `/` and `/manage`, and the action for the index page is a simple redirect to the action that you want to forward on to.

The other option is to front your Play server with an HTTP server, like Apache or Lighttp, and perform the redirect within the HTTP server config. This is actually what the `http.path` is meant to be used for, to help play applications co-exist in an existing web server environment.

Comment: My app is indeed not hosted at the root - I'm merely looking for a way to make `/` also point to `/manage/` - this is for internal development purposes, not for production use (so I won't configure an apache locally just for this).

Comment: How about writing a simple play app, that the index action simply redirects to `/manage'. I can't think of any other way. It a waste of memory, I know, but if it is for internal purposes only, then I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: How would that work? Can I run multiple Play apps if I `play start` all of them? I don't think I can - doesn't this try to raise multiple instances that all bind on the same port?

Comment: yes, good point...forgot about the port!! Guess there is no answer, unless you use apache to front the http

Comment: OK, I'll accept for now because odds are there is no solution a.t.m.